# "Позвони и узнай(,) почему" — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая в фразе: "Позвони и узнай(,)почему"?

Answer (score 4):

Розенталь говорит, что придаточное предложение, состоящее из одного слова(обычно союза или союзного слова), запятой не отделяется

Answer (score 2):

Запятая не нужна. Посмотрите [параграф 142, приложение 2](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=zap&text=19_26).

"Примечание 2. Придаточное предложение, состоящее из одного только союза или относительного слова, не отделяется запятой, например:
– Откуда? 
Я сказал откуда.

М. Горький"